# how to add a widget which has two spinner items and put in a single dialog in android

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-alertdialog, customdialog

I am trying to design confirmation dialog which has two lists (scrollable). One part shows numbers of foot and another shows inches values. This should be in a single dialog as shown in the image below. Any suggestions to do this is appreciated.

[image: see this image]

*I achieved this UI by using the following code*
**mycustomwidget.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="@string/txtHeight"
        android:id="@+id/tvHeight" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:id="@+id/editText_Height"
        android:hint="select Height"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in my Activity is used this code to get the dialog

```
editText_Height.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ProfileInfo.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.height_picker);
    dialog.show();
    }
});
```

heightpicker.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txtHeight"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/border_bottom">
        <com.myapp.HelperClasses.MyNumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/footValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            max="7"
            min="4" />
        <com.myapp.HelperClasses.MyNumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/inchValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            max="11"
            min="0" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_cancel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:text="@string/txtCancel"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_Okay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="@string/txtOkay"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you need to use number picker

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Can you post the codes?

Comment: i guess you could use an alertdialog with the layout you desire. i guess use a two numberpicker and maybe an array of inches and feet

Comment: did you try with my answer?

Comment: @Naveen, plz paste some code so that we know what have you done so far?

Comment: Height_picker.xml
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/footValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/inchValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout> 

now trying to call this inside a fragment

Comment: @Aditya Vyas I want this to be shown in a dialog, so it's taking time for me

Comment: simply put numberpikcer in alertdailog

Comment: i was able to add UI part, but unable to inflate with ok and cancel button to the alertdialog, also i'm inflating in the main Activity not in a dialog. correct if i'm doing the wrong way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NumberPicker](http://sampleprogramz.com/android/numberpicker.php) like this way

```
<NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"  />
```

Java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    NumberPicker np;
    TextView tv1, tv2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

        np.setMinValue(0);
        np.setMaxValue(10);
        np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false); 

        np.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String Old = "Old Value : ";
            String New = "New Value : ";

            tv1.setText(Old.concat(String.valueOf(oldVal)));
            tv2.setText(New.concat(String.valueOf(newVal)));
        }
    });
    }
```

Comment: on click or on focus of an edittext, i want to show this on a dialog, now that i'm able to inflate UI with out Ok and cancel Button, also i should be able to have control over action listeners.

Comment: what is the issue then?

Comment: unable to inflate UI using DialogFragment

Comment: what do you mean UI?

Comment: hi, i want to add single quote and double quote to the Number picker, using this.setMinValue(attrs.getAttributeIntValue(null, "min", 0)); i dont know how to append those symbols, do you have any idea ???

Comment: you need to make custom array for text and add that array in numberpicker..and accept my answer if it helped you

Comment: ok thanks... it helped me

Comment: can you accept answer if it helped?

Comment: i accepted it, but i dont have enough points to reflect on your answer